# Backstage oAuth Github: Missing session cookie

Tags: node.js, github, cookies, cross-domain, backstage

Hope you're doing well! I'm looking for some kind of help. Will be really grateful for you if you provide me with some sort of a hint.

I'm setting up developer portal based on [Backstage.io][1] according to Getting started docs instructions.

I've added @backstage/plugin-auth-backend to the project root and configured it as described [here][2].

As soon as I try to load backstage web app I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"name":"AuthenticationError","message":"Refresh failed; caused by InputError: Missing session cookie"
```

And it's followed by the list of .ts files with errors including some scripts connected with node_modules/@backstage/plugin-auth-backend. Guys, really I don't know where I'm missing something.

Here are some key points in my app-config.yaml:

```
app:
  title: Scaffolded Backstage App
  baseUrl: http://0.0.0.0:3000

backend:
  baseUrl: http://<publicIP>:7007
  listen:
    port: 7007
csp:
    default-src: ["'self'", 'http:', 'https:']
    connect-src: ["'self'", 'http:', 'https:']
    script-src: ["'self", 'http:', 'https:','unsafe-inline', http://www.github.com", http://api.github.com"]
cors:
    origin: http://*:3000
    methods: [GET, POST, PUT, DELETE]
    credentials: true
    headers: X-Requested-With

auth:
  environment: development
  providers:
    github:
      development:
        clientId: ${GITHUB_CLIENTID}
        clientSecret: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

I have exported those env variables to current terminal and ran `yarn dev`

So when I try to login to Backstage using Github I get `401 Unathorized` error response while trying to approach thar Request URL: `http://<publicIP>:7007/api/auth/github/refresh?optional&env=development`
[1]: https://backstage.io/
[2]: https://backstage.io/docs/auth/add-auth-provider

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Comment: I have just solved this. But the solution was probably specific to me. The problem why the cookie is not set is because verification with provider failed. In my case, the company man in the middle proxy blocked the request from me to GitHub servers. But application did not fire any error, only the cookie was not set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! So, have you faced the error like "invalid X-Requested-With header"  while trying to authenticate via Github provider. Have you applied some changes to the source code of backstage app that are not included by getting started guide? I know that auth backend for most auth providers including Github are included in backstage by default or am I mistaken? I'm using the VM on GCP so I don't think it's an issue with some mitm proxy. Maybe we can chat somewhere outside the stack...

Comment: Any update on this ? I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

They currently are changing the way to configure auth.

There's a discussion ongoing on this topic: https://github.com/backstage/backstage/issues/23748

I was able to configure auth for GitHub in backstage on the **localhost** backstage instance.

Prerequisites:

- [OAuth application](https://github.com/settings/developers) is configured in GitHub

  - Authorization callback URL is `http://localhost:7007/api/auth/github`
- User email is visible and selected on the corresponding user profile settings in GitHub

Added configuration:

- `app-config.yaml` (note `resolvers` section)

```
auth:
  # see https://backstage.io/docs/auth/ to learn about auth providers
  environment: production
  providers:
    guest: {}
    github:
      production:
        clientId: <valueOrVar> 
        clientSecret: <valueOrVar>
        signIn:
          resolvers:
            - resolver: emailMatchingUserEntityProfileEmail
            - resolver: emailLocalPartMatchingUserEntityName
            - resolver: usernameMatchingUserEntityName
```

- `packages/backend/src/index.ts`

```
backend.add(import('@backstage/plugin-auth-backend-module-github-provider'));
```

- `packages/app/src/App.tsx` (documentation is wrong here: no need to import SignInPage; read comments carefully to the next snippet)

```
// add import
import { githubAuthApiRef } from '@backstage/core-plugin-api';
// add the following in createApp function after 'apis,' line
  components: {
    SignInPage: props => (
      <SignInPage
      {...props}
      auto
      provider={{
        id: 'github-auth-provider',
        title: 'GitHub',
        message: 'Sign in using GitHub',
        apiRef: githubAuthApiRef,
      }}
      />
    ),
  },
```

- `examples/org.yaml`: change guest to the GitHub username